# Programmatically check if a D8 version exists for all site modules

Tags: 8

I am listing all modules used by site on our platform. Given a module name, how could I programmatically check if a Drupal 8 version is available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to consume the update feed, e.g.:

http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/module_filter/8.x

Gives you

```
<error>No release history available for module_filter 8.x.</error>
```

While

http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/views/8.x

gives you

```
<project xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
<title>Views</title>
<short_name>views</short_name>
<dc:creator>merlinofchaos</dc:creator>
<type>project_module</type>
<api_version>8.x</api_version>
<project_status>unsupported</project_status>
<link>https://www.drupal.org/project/views</link>
<terms>
<term>
<name>Projects</name>
<value>Modules</value>
</term>
<term>
<name>Maintenance status</name>
<value>Seeking co-maintainer(s)</value>
</term>
<term>
<name>Development status</name>
<value>Under active development</value>
</term>
</terms>
<releases>
<release>
<name>views 8.x-3.x-dev</name>
<version>8.x-3.x-dev</version>
<tag>8.x-3.x</tag>
<version_major>3</version_major>
<version_extra>dev</version_extra>
<status>published</status>
<release_link>https://www.drupal.org/node/1595020</release_link>
<download_link>http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-8.x-3.x-dev.tar.gz</download_link>
<date>1382152087</date>
<mdhash>b1adfb5f2d048e004fd830754546c8f9</mdhash>
<filesize>491125</filesize>
<files>
<file>
<url>http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-8.x-3.x-dev.tar.gz</url>
<archive_type>tar.gz</archive_type>
<md5>b1adfb5f2d048e004fd830754546c8f9</md5>
<size>491125</size>
<filedate>1382152087</filedate>
</file>
<file>
<url>http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-8.x-3.x-dev.zip</url>
<archive_type>zip</archive_type>
<md5>67579f47179eeeadf43b7d7501b9cf81</md5>
<size>816701</size>
<filedate>1382152088</filedate>
</file>
</files>
</release>
</releases>
</project>
```

Comment: This is the theoretically correct answer, the real answer is @Jonathan 's.

Answer (score 3):

For non programmatical way.

Download and install the [Upgrade Status](https://www.drupal.org/project/upgrade_status) Module

Answer (score 1):

nothing to be particularly proud about but in case it can help somebody out :

```
 foreach ($list_modules as $name => $modules){   

$feed_url="http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/".strtolower($name)."/8.x";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($feed_url);

 $d8='no D8 version';   
foreach($xml->children() as $child)
{
    $childname= $child->getName();

    if($childname == "releases")
    {
        $d8='';
        foreach ($child->release as $release){
            $d8.=$release->version.' - ';
        }
        $output.='<a href='.$feed_url.'><div class="versiond8">'.$d8.'</div></a>';      
    }   
}

if ($d8=='no D8 version')
    $output.='<div class="versiond8">'.$d8.'</div>';


$module_url='https://www.drupal.org/project/'.$name;    
$output.='<a href='.$module_url.'><div class="drupal_site">module doc</div></a>';


}
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can programatically check whether a D8 version is nominally available, the reality is much more complex. Sometimes they are available but not working, sometimes they are deprecated in favour of a new module, sometimes in core, other times there is a fully working but unofficial version that a programtic approach would not find.

I see no worthwhile alternative to looking closely at each module.

Answer (score 0):

Simply to track for your own purposes so you can monitor the general state of your site, see http://d8upgrade.org/

I started using their service a while back when you had to send them a list of modules. They now claim to have a way to scan your site and build the list automatically. They also maintain a module database for modules with over 300(?) users.